# Chicken breast sous vide: Time in fridge matters?

Tags: food-safety, sous-vide, chicken-breast

I have kept a chicken breast, packed in plastic (possibly in a near-vacuum environment) in my fridge for more than a week. The best-before-date is tomorrow. I am considering cooking this breast sous vide at 65 C for 1,5hours. It is about 2.5cm thick. Would this be considered safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Douglas Baldwin [pasteurisation tables for poultry](http://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Chicken_or_Turkey_Breast) a chicken breast of that thickness would be pasteurised after 55 minutes so you are well within that range.

```
Thickness   57°C    58°C    59°C    60°C    61°C    62°C    63°C    64°C    65°C
   20 mm    2¾ hr   2 hr    1¾ hr   1¼ hr   1¼ hr   55 min  50 min  45 min  40 min
   25 mm    3 hr    2¼ hr   2 hr    1½ hr   1½ hr   1¼ hr   1¼ hr   60 min  55 min
   30 mm    3¼ hr   2¾ hr   2¼ hr   2 hr    1¾ hr   1½ hr   1½ hr   1¼ hr   1¼ hr
```